Counterexample for familiy of equicontinuous and pointwise bounded functions that is not uniformly bounded
I aware of the theorem such that
"Let $(f_n)$ equicontinuous and pointwise bounded sequence of real-valued functions on a compact metric space then $(f_n)$ is  uniformly bounded."
What if I change the condition "compactness" into "bounded set".
Is it still valid? I try to get a counterexample but can't find one. Any tips would be great.
Thanks in advance for you help.

@daw for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n=1/x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ so that $(f_n)$ is not (uniformly) equicontinuous . I think that this example won't work

Take $X = \mathbb R$ with discrete metric
$$
d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x \ne y,\\
0 & \text{ if } x=y.
\end{cases}.
$$
Then $X$ is bounded, consists of  infinitely many isolated points, and is not compact. Every function $f: X \to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous but not necessarily bounded. Then take an unbounded function $f$ and set $f_n :=f $ for all $n$.

Such a construction does not work if $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ is bounded: we could replace $X$ by its closure, and extend $f_n$ to $\bar X$. This extension is possible since $f_n$ is assumed to be uniformly continuous. It follows that these extensions are uniformly bounded.
